# Issue with getting Justified Gallery working within Bootstrap 4 Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, bootstrap-4

I have a page I'm trying to complete that has a tabbed inner menu system, and within them (the first and last tab) there are justified galleries

http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

The code works well within the first tab, but when I put it within the last tab it turns all the images into thumbnails 80px by 80px. I initially thought that perhaps this was limited to one gallery per page, so I did some testing and I was able to add another one outside of the tabs with no issue.

I did some further testing and figured out that the reason it was working in the first tab and not the last was because the first tab has an active class on it, making the div a block element (`display: block`) and as soon as I put active on the other tab it made the gallery work but obviously broke the tabs.

At this point I'm stuck as to what I can do to get this to work, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out a little. Below is the code, thanks!

```
<div class="middleContent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 leftContent">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#orderOnline" role="tab">Menu</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#reviews" role="tab">Reviews</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#about" role="tab">About</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#photos" role="tab">Photos</a> </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="orderOnline" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>MENU</h2>

                <div id="mygallery" >
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-10.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-10.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-11.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-11.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-12.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-12.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-13.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-13.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-14.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-14.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-15.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-15.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </div>


            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="reviews" role="tabpanel">
            <h2>Reviews</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="about" role="tabpanel">
            <h2>About</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="photos" role="tabpanel">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Food</h2>

                    <div id="foodgallery">
                        <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-10.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-10.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-11.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-11.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-12.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-12.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-13.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-13.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-14.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-14.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="menu-gallery" href="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-15.jpg">
                        <img alt="imgSEO" src="images/restaurantPage/imagemenu/238-m-15.jpg"/>
                    </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#mygallery').justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight: 300,
        lastRow: 'nojustify',
        randomize: false,
        margins: 10
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#foodgallery').justifiedGallery({
            rowHeight: 200,
            lastRow: 'nojustify',
            randomize: false,
            margins: 10
        });
    }); 
</script>
```